# how can i get JSON object from controller in my view and use it in Jquery function?

Tags: json, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to return JSON from my controller and get it in my view .this is my code, when i debug it . goes to my controller and get value but in my j query code nothing happen .when i debug my j query code  by firebug it dos not run the function(data). what is wrong in my code ?i want get object of part-booklet from server. its a row of data and add this row to my Telerik mvc grid .thanks in advance 
its my contoroller code:

```
 #region dynamic_add_row_to_grid
     private PartBooklet GetPartBooklet( int sparepart ) {
        return _PartBookletService.GetList().Where(m => m.SparePartCode == sparepart).FirstOrDefault();
     }

     [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
     public JsonResult GetItems( int sparepart ) {
         var PartbookletList = this.GetPartBooklet(sparepart);
         return Json(PartbookletList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
     #endregion
```

and its jquery code:

```
    $("#btnadd").button().click( function () {
        alert("button");
        var sparepartcode = $("#SparePartCode").val();
        alert( sparepartcode );
        $.getJSON("../Shared/GetItems", { sparepart: sparepartcode }, function( data ) {
           alert( data.val );
           alert("PartbookletList");
           var grid = $('#InvoiceItemGrid').data('tGrid');
           grid.dataBind( data );
        }).error( function () {
           alert("JSON call failed");
        });

        $( function () {
           $.ajaxSetup({
           error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
              if ( jqXHR.status === 0 ) {
                  alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
              } else if ( jqXHR.status == 404 ) {
                  alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
              } else if ( jqXHR.status == 500 ) {
                  alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
              } else if (exception === 'parsererror' ) {
                  alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
              } else if ( exception === 'timeout' ) {
                  alert('Time out error.');
              } else if ( exception === 'abort' ) {
                  alert('Ajax request aborted.');
              } else {
                  alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
              }
            }
         });
     });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnadd").button().click( function () {
    //alert("button");
    var sparepartcode = $("#SparePartCode").val();

    $.ajax({
            url: "/Shared/GetItem?sparepart=" + sparepartcode,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(a, b, data) {
                //alert( data.val );
                alert("PartbookletList");
                var grid = $('#InvoiceItemGrid').data('tGrid');
                grid.dataBind( data );
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("JSON call failed");
            },
            // other options and setup ...
    });
});
```

Note that in a successful ajax request, it's the 3rd parameter that contains the actual data you need.